# Jargon for when your site's bandwidth quota is eaten up by traffic from a backlink in a popular blog?

Tags: backlinks, high-traffic, availability, terminology

This happens every now and then on the web. Charlie has a personal blog where they posts about technical stuff. One day a popular site finds about their posts, and decides to do an article on it, linking to the source, of course.

The incoming traffic eats up Charlie's provider's bandwidth quota, and is taken down by the provider.

Is there a term for this unavailability of a site due to unexpected traffic from suddenly being famous?

Answer (score 2):

It's called [the Slashdot effect](http://searchmicroservices.techtarget.com/definition/Slashdot-Effect).

> The Slashdot Effect is the sudden, relatively temporary surge in traffic to a Web site that occurs when a high-traffic Web site or other source posts a story that refers visitors to another Web site.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect):

> The Slashdot effect, also known as slashdotting, occurs when a popular website links to a smaller site, causing a massive increase in traffic. This overloads the smaller site, causing it to slow down or even temporarily become unavailable. The name stems from the huge influx of web traffic that would result from the technology news site Slashdot linking to websites.

Slashdot doesn't deliver this kind of traffic anymore but the name has stuck.

Comment: Wow that was fast. I think the language barrier prevented me from finding the term on a search, but fortunately the question doesn't seem to be a dupe. XD

Comment: I just happen to be looking at the site when you asked this. At one point in time this was a holy grail of webmasters as many would *kill* to get that kind of exposure. (And probably still would).

Comment: It also is known as Reddit Hug of Death or HN Hug Of Death